# WiFi Download Capped at 5 Mbps

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

All of a sudden the WiFi download on my personal Dell laptop seems to be capped at 5 Mbps on a connection of 40 Mbps. Laptop is right next to the router. I was getting 40 just few days back.

I'm getting 40 Mbps on all other devices & getting 40 on the laptop via Ethernet. Just not on WiFi. Same cap when connected to hotspots as well, so it's definitely something with the machine. The upload seems to be fine.

Things I've tried:

1. Update the Wireless card drivers from Intel & Dell's sites to
   latest.
2. Flushed DNS & all the cmd prompt commands to renew everything
3. Uninstalled & reinstalled wireless card several times
4. Reset the settings on my router
5. Reset WiFi settings several times

I'm pulling my hair out. Please help.

P.S: I know the difference between MBps & Mbps. All references are in Mbps.

System Info

- The Router is an old one & uses 2.4 GHz (B+G+N) & the Wireless card is at Dual Band 802.11a/b/g mode (Has been like this since forever). No settings changed.
- Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299
- System Manufacturer   Dell Inc.
- System Model  Inspiron 5547
- System Type   x64-based PC
- Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz, 2601 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4
- Logical Processor(s)
- Installed Physical Memory (RAM)   8.00 GB
- Intel dual band wireless AC-3160

Comment: What 802.11 Standard is each of your devices using and at which frequency.  **Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment**

Comment: Verify you are connected by 802.11ac 5.0 GHz instead of 802.11 2.4 GHz.  Edit your question question.

Comment: @Ramhound Just did. Router is at 2.4GHz B+G+N, Wireless card at dual band 802.11a/b/g. Was getting speed in these same settings. My router only supports 2.4GHz. https://vgy.me/K6JbQV.png https://vgy.me/XZikNI.png https://vgy.me/ImENNp.png

Answer (score 0):

With all the steps you already did, I can only see one possible issue left.

1. Open a cmd prompt with admin privileges
2. Type `netsh int tcp show global`
3. check if "**Receive Window Auto-tuning Level**" is set to normal or disabled
4. if disabled then type `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal`
5. check if "**RFC 1323 Timestamps**" are disabled
6. if not then type `netsh int tcp set global timestamps=disabled`

Thats it, I hope that this will solve your problem.

PS1: **Window auto-tuning is a Windows feature designed to automatically improve the performance of programs that receive TCP data over a network**. I get few more mbps of dowmload speed and upload speed with this feature enabled vs disabled, but doesn't help with the ping.

PS2: **RFC 1323 is a TCP enhancement for improving performance and reliability when transmitting data**. In my case (on both windows 10 and windows 11), when it is enabled my download speed is capped at 50% of its regular speed, and my ping is 4 times higher than when it is disabled. so I guess that this feature doesn't work as intended so far, further improvements are needed.

Comment: Could you explain (in your answer) what these settings actually do, and why they would help?

Comment: @StarCat I edited my answer, thank you for the comment.